# Get values in column between two dates in another columns in Python Django

Tags: python, django, date

kindly request function to get and calculates values in between time period with Python-Django function

the database example will be as below

- Case(1)    start_time = 01-11-2019    end_time = 15-12-2019    rate = 35.00
- Case(2)    start_time = 16-12-2019    end_time = 31-12-2019    rate = 50.00

i need function to calculate the rate as following:

user will request the period from 13-12-2019 till 18-12-2019
rate calculated [(13, 14, 15 December) = 35+35+35 = 105] + [(16, 17 , 18 
December = 50+50+50 = 150] with total rate finally 255

```
class Items(models.Model): 
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)

class Item(models.Model): 
  name = models.ForeignKey(Items, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  start_date = models.DateField()
  end_date = models.DateField()
  rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. However, I'd be worried about multiple `Item` instances covering the same range of dates. If that's a real possibility, then the below function won't work properly.

```
request_lower = some_date
request_upper = some_other_date

items_within_range = Item.objects.filter(
    Q(start_date__lte=request_lower, end_date__gt=request_lower)
    | Q(start_date__lte=request_upper, end_date__gt=request_upper)
)

total = 0
for index in range((request_upper - request_lower).days):
    # Iterate over the days from lower to upper.
    date = request_lower + timedelta(days=index)
    # Find the Item instance that the date is within the range.
    total += [
        i.rate for i in items_within_range
        if i.start_date <= date < i.end_date
    ][0]
```

Comment: If I have multiple instance what can I do

Comment: That depends on what you want to happen.

Comment: If I have 2 items for example (room standard  & room deluxe) with same dates but different rates

Comment: What would you want to have happen?